# Random questions in the "newest" tab come with background colour

Tags: support, tag-watching

I have noticed recently, that random questions appear with light orange (debatable) background colour like :

> [image]

I could not make out why is this happening.

Any significance of this?

For assistance :

My favourite tags are :

> [image]

Comment: It means that it is tagged with one of your favorite tags.

Comment: java is my favourite tag, and all of the questions are tagged with java. So all questions should be with coloured background.

Comment: Is it your only fav tag?

Comment: I think I got it!!!

Comment: Wat exactly did you got?

Comment: When in tag page, you need to have one more favorite tag to have it colored.

Comment: Javascript is extra, and as I am in Java newest questions. It considers Javascript.

Comment: @Bat ok, great :)

Comment: @nicael Can you please add this as answer, may be will be helpful to others

Comment: Ok, I posted an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow background is applied to the questions which are tagged with some of your favorite tags.

> [image]

When you are viewing questions for some tag which is in your favorites, only questions, which have your *other* favorite tags would be highlighted.

> [image]